# How to take Date from sql db as a single result and compare with current date

Tags: mysql, sql, jsf, date

i have a complex problem with Date field. Describe what i want to do:

1. I have field date1 as Date in my db.

   ```
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   private Date date1;
   ```
2. I want to take data from this field and compare with current date.

   ```
   @Query("SELECT date1 FROM Table io WHERE io.date1 >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-%e')")

    Date findAll2();

   public boolean CheckDate1(){


       currentDate = new Date();

       date1 = getInterimOrdersRepo().findAll2();

       if(currentDate.before(date1) || currentDate.equals(date1)){
       System.out.println("TRUE");

       System.out.println("currentDate = "+currentDate);
      return true;
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("FALSE");
           return false;
       }
       }
   ```

but i have an error:

```
 result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException
```

1. When method return false i want do Update field data1 with " " empty data.

I using jsf, what i must to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to read several values from the table into a single variable, and that is the error. 
findall2 returns an array (most likely) and u should read one of it's values - try reading first one.

Furthermore, I believe that you can skip the "DATE_FORMAT" in your query, and this is a very strange way to write a code. Not clear what u are trying to achieve here